# How to call all unique values in variables to simplify the code?

Tags: python, pandas

I had this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/elnahas/gender-inequality-in-hiv-infections-in-adolescents). At first I am trying to assess the normality for all columns with missing values (Death Rate, Death, Incidence, and HIV Cases). I tried using this code (df3 is the dataframe for the dataset):

```
from scipy.stats import shapiro
norm_dr= shapiro(df3["AIDS_Death_Rate"].dropna())
norm_d= shapiro(df3["AIDS_Death"].dropna())
norm_inc= shapiro(df3["HIV_Incidence_Rate"].dropna())
norm_nc= shapiro(df3["New_HIV_Cases"].dropna())
print("normality for aids death rate: ", norm_dr,
     "normality for aids death: ", norm_d,
     "normality for incidence: ", norm_inc,
     "normality for new cases: ", norm_nc)
```

While the code were running perfectly, I feel like it drains so much energy to write down all the column. The column was sequentially located next to each other so I thought I could run something like:

```
norm= shaphiro (df3[3:6).dropna())
print(norm)
```

But to no avail

Comment: Loop over the columns and calculate the normality for each one. Use `df.columns` to iterate over the column names, which you can use later for printing or assigning dictionary keys.

Comment: "But to no avail" - **What happened** when you tried this code, and **how is that different** from what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension to create a list of column names you want to check for normality, and then loop through that list to call the shapiro function on each column. Here's how you can do it:

```
from scipy.stats import shapiro

cols_to_check = ["AIDS_Death_Rate", "AIDS_Death", "HIV_Incidence_Rate", "New_HIV_Cases"]

normality_results = []
for col in cols_to_check:
    normality_results.append(shapiro(df3[col].dropna()))

for col, result in zip(cols_to_check, normality_results):
    print(f"Normality for {col}: {result}")
```

If you want some more concise way to achieve this without explicitly listing all the column names, you can use the columns attribute of the DataFrame to get a list of all column names, and then filter out the columns you want based on certain criteria. Here's how you can do it:

```
from scipy.stats import shapiro

cols_with_missing = [col for col in df3.columns if df3[col].isnull().any()]

normality_results = []
for col in cols_with_missing:
    normality_results.append(shapiro(df3[col].dropna()))

for col, result in zip(cols_with_missing, normality_results):
    print(f"Normality for {col}: {result}")
```

This approach dynamically identifies the columns with missing values and performs the normality test on those columns, without needing to explicitly list the column names. If you already know the columns you need to normalize, you can assign `cols_to_check` accordingly. For example,`cols_to_check = df3.columns[2:6]`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the columns like this

```
norm = {}
for k in df3.columns[3:7]:
    norm[k] = shaphiro(df3[k].dropna())
```

Comment: Good call. Faster without list